# Calculating the limit of a function is apparantly leading to absurd results

Tags: calculus, limits

I started studying calculus recently, and when i apply the basic concepts and algebra of limits to find this limit 'A' i end up with an absurd result and i can't figure out what i am doing wrong here
$$ 
\lim _{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{f(x) g(x)}{h}=A
 $$
$$ 
\lim _{h \rightarrow 0} f(x) \lim _{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{g(x+h)}{h}
 $$
$$ 
\lim _{h \rightarrow 0} f(x) \lim _{h \rightarrow 0}\left[\frac{g(x+h)-g(x)}{h}+\frac{g(x)}{h}\right]
 $$
$$ 
\lim _{h \rightarrow 0} f(x)\left[g^{\prime}(x)+\lim _{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{g(x)}{h}\right]
 $$
$$ 
f(x) g^{\prime}(x)+\lim _{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{f(x) g(x)}{h}
 $$
$$ 
f(x) g^{\prime}(x)+A
 $$
So i started out with A and apparantly did not do anything to change it and yet ended up with A plus something, which is absurd. What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $fg$ is $h$-independent, your original limit doesn't exist (although  a one-sided limit would be $\pm\infty$) unless $fg=0$, in which case $A=0$.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming $A\in \mathbb R$, we have that if $$\lim _{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{f(x) g(x)}{h}=A$$ then it must be $f(x)g(x)=A=0.$